# SELECT, WHERE, GROUP BY

Tags: sql, group-by, mariadb, where-clause

I'm trying to retrieve data that shows me if a card has been given to a player.

I've tried different ways of structuring the code using these sites are resources

http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-group-by/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

But I keeping getting this error message

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(E_Subtype WHERE E_Type = 'Card') GROUP BY E_From LIMIT 0, 25'
>   at line 2

```sql
SELECT E_Type, E_Subtype FROM eventdataview
COUNT (E_Subtype WHERE E_Type = 'Card')
GROUP BY E_From;
```

I'm trying to fetch data from E_type and E_Subtype to show is a card has been given. 
If a card has been given it will look at E_From to see which player received the card.

Should look something like this

```
E_From     | E_Subtype
-----------|-----------
player 1   | Yellow Card
Player 2   | Red Card
```

Comment: `SELECT E_Type, E_Subtype, COUNT (E_Subtype)  FROM eventdataview
WHERE E_Type = 'Card'
GROUP BY E_From`

Comment: You're looking at a SQL Server tutorial while your error message is from MariaDB. They're two different databases and not always compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is at

COUNT (E_Subtype WHERE E_Type = 'Card')

Parentheses at wrong place, as well as count of a column added after the table name.

Use the query as @andrew mentioned below

```
SELECT E_Type, E_Subtype, COUNT (E_Subtype) As No_Of_Subtypes 
FROM eventdataview 
WHERE E_Type = 'Card' 
GROUP BY E_From
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT E_Type, COUNT(*)
FROM eventdataview
WHERE E_Type = 'Card'
GROUP BY E_From;
```

Notes:

- The clauses of SQL go in a very specific order, `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`.
- In an aggregation query, the only unaggregated expressions should have only `GROUP BY` keys.
- `WHERE` is a clause for the entire query, not for the `COUNT()` function.